# Difficulties compiling fortran .f95 file, how to debug?

Tags: debugging, fortran, gfortran

I am trying to learn fortran. I wanted to replicate a certain step in a paper but I ran into trouble.

I compiled the file AERsimulation.f95 (I turned on all debugging functions in gfortran I am aware of) I could generate an .out file without any errors (a lot of warnings, however...)

When I tried to run the .out file I got the error message

> Fortran runtime error: Index '0' of dimension 1 of array 'k' below lower bound of 1

Now, it is quite difficult for me to understand why exactly this happens. I guess, my question is, whether there is a better way of debugging, so that I can see and click through the code 'live' and see why the error occurs. (I am thinking of the matlab-debugger for instance...)

Any suggestion/hint is very welcome

The files I use are

[AERsimulation.f95](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ormpxm8fmsyj8fb/AERsimulation.f95?dl=0)

[AERDATANB.TXT](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1wgoaokwo1pnkks/AERDATANB.TXT?dl=0)

Thank you very much
Best
Derrick

Comment: Normally, gfortran also prints the line number, where the error happens. You can use some good text editor to point you there in the source code (I use `kate`, but mostly I go to the right place manually anyway). Be sure to use `gfortran -g -fbacktrace -fcheck=all -Wall`.

Comment: BTW, do not use `.f95`, use just `.f90` for any free-form source. I suppose you do not want rename your file once you add a feature from f03 or f08.

Answer (score 2):

The meaning of your error message is that you try to access an array element at the position 0 of the array. Arrays in Fortran start at 1 by default.

If you are looking for a better way to debug, try gdb (command line) or if you prefer a graphical interface you can try the Netbeans IDE. It has (limited) support for Fortran an a debugging mode where you can click line by line through the code and see the values of all variables and so on.

On command line try:

```
gdb name_of_executable
run
```

the debugger will stop at the line which causes the error.